# Syntax questions: What is right to do?

Tags: html, css, syntax

If I have a child inside a div with an id, for example, `id="mother"`, how correctly to write css?

Example:

1) `#mother ul li {...}`

or

2) `mother ul li {...}`

Is there a difference? The second example I saw when MOTHER had a class name, not id.

Comment: No offence but that's CSS 101: `mother` applies to `<mother>`, just like `div` applies to `<div>`.

Comment: `#mother` for id, `mother` for a `<mother>` tag, and `.mother` for `class="mother"`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach is the right one
when you have:

HTML:

```
<div id="mother">
     <ul>
         <li>first child</li>
         <li>secondchild</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mother ul li {
    color:red;
}
```

Your second approach have to change like this:

```
div ul li {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `mother` is a type selector. It matches `<mother>`
- `#mother` is an id selector. It matches elements with `id="mother"`.
- `.mother` is a class selector. It matches elements with `class="mother and-possibly-other-classes"`.

See [the selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) for more.

Comment: Thanks for being nice to me as anewbie back then. :) Upvoted after almost 5 years

Answer (score -1):

First one is correct with using id, second one is for class but with a 'dot' in-front of class name.

eg1:

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
<ul>
<li></li>
.........
.........
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 ul li{

}
```

eg2:

HTML

```
<div class="div1">
<ul>
<li></li>
.........
.........
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 ul li{

}
```